# How to remove checkbox, and style label, when label tag wraps checkbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Advanced beginner here so please be patient:)

I have had some luck removing `checkboxes` and styling their `labels` where the `for=""` attribute exists.

On one particular form I'm trying to style, the markup is quite different and the `labels` are wrapping the `input` and there is no `for` attribute.

The markup is thus..

```
<li id='tags-234'>
  <label class="selectit">
    <input value="234" type="checkbox" 
           name="tax_input[tags][]" id="in-tags-234" /> Tag 1
  </label>
</li>
```

Can anyone get me started? Do I need to add label tags, somehow, first?

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I get it, what are you trying to do here? The question is marked with so many tags it's hard to know which one you're after? Do you want to just remove the label and checkbox with jQuery, or do you want to target them with CSS ... or what ?

Comment: Yeah like I said.."Advanced Beginner" :) 

Anyway I'm trying to replace checkboxes with styled labels that have 2 states ie checked and unchecked. I have done this before where the markup was different. Cant work this one out at all...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to remove the checkbox and style the label, but here's how you can do it with your HTML structure:

```js
// Get reference to all labels that don't have a "for" attribute:
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("label:not([for])");

// Turn that node list into a JavaScript array:
var lblArray = Array.from(labels);

// Loop through the array:
lblArray.forEach(function(lbl){
  lbl.removeChild(lbl.firstElementChild);  // remove the child content
  lbl.classList.add("someStyle");          // style the label by adding a class to it 
});
```

```css
.someStyle {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<li id='tags-234'>
  <label class="selectit">
    <input value="234" type="checkbox" 
           name="tax_input[tags][]" id="in-tags-234" /> Tag 1
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Well that was quick :) So thank you very much of course. I'm not 100% sure where to go next so if I may impose one more time.

1. I'm using Wordpress. Can I put that JS directly in the header?

2. The idea behind styling the label is so that I can show 2 different states ie. checked and not checked. will I be able to accomplish this with this markup do you think? I know I will need to add further css and use the :checked pseudo class at some point.

Comment: @BrianyHearne I'm sorry, I can't say since I don't have much experience with Word Press. My gut says no. If this answer has helped with your posted question, please up vote it and mark it as the answer. Then, I would suggest making another question (tagged with Word Press) that asks specifically how to add custom JavaScript into a Word Press document.

Comment: @BrianyHearne We're happy to help here, but please understand how the site works. It's best to post a new question when you've got new problems that the original question didn't ask for.

Comment: Yes understood. I hit return thinking it would drop down a line but instead it posted the question. Sorry about that.